# Declaring a hex constant in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, hex, constants

How can I convert the following C# hexadecimal into a [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) hexadecimal?

```
private const UInt32 temp = 0xE6359A60;
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
Public Const temp As System.UInt32 = 0xE6359A60
```

Comment: [Private Const temp As UInt32 = &He6359a60UI](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**C# uses `0x` and [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) uses `&H` as the prefix to specify hexadecimal numbers.**
try this.

```
Public Const temp As Integer = &HE6359A60

Sub Main

End Sub
```

And it could be as Uint also:

```
Public Const temp As UInt32 = &HE6359A60UI

Sub Main

End Sub
```

Check MSDN's [Type Characters (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx) documentation for defining hexadecimal and octal literals:

> The compiler normally construes an integer literal to be in the
>   decimal (base 10) number system. You can force an integer literal to
>   be **hexadecimal (base 16)** with the **&H prefix**, and you can force it to
>   be **octal (base 8)** with the **&O prefix**. The digits that follow the
>   prefix must be appropriate for the number system.

References:

- *[Hex number (not ASCII hex value) to string in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747709) (Stack Overflow)*
- *[What does &H57 represent and how can I translate it for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206763) (Stack Overflow)*

Comment: In `&HE6359A60` (VB) and `0xE6359A60` (C#)  `E` is part of the number, not of the prefix, since `E` is a valid hex digit. The valid prefix is `&H` in VB, without the `E`!

Answer (score 3):

```
Public Const temp As Integer = &H6359A60
```

Prefix it with `&H`

Comment: No, in VB prefix it with `&H` only instead of `0x` as in C#.