# How check a character not betwwen F900~FAFF?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want get text , character not betwwen `F900~FAFF`:

```
Dim inTexts="abc豈あああ"
    　　　　Dim i As Integer
            Dim tmpChr As String
            toUniCodeHex = ""
            For i = 0 To Len(inTexts) - 1
                tmpChr = AscW(inTexts.Substring(i, 1)).ToString("x4")
               *’ How check tmpChr not betwwen F900~FAFF?*
            Next
```

How check a character not betwwen `F900~FAFF`?
Thanks all.

Comment: Don't convert the number back into a string, just compare the numbers. [For hexadecimal numbers in VB, see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240587/declaring-a-hex-constant-in-vb-net).

Comment: Also, using a `for` loop and `Substring` seems unnecessary since `string` already implements `IEnumerable<Char>` to allow you to inspect each character in turn.

Comment: Can we check "a" not between F900~FAFF?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to ask since most of the code you've shown is mechanism and more work than you need. Are you looking for e.g. a simple boolean `true` or `false` result? If so, what are you trying to determine? Is it "does this string contain *any* character in the forbidden range?" or "does this string *only* contain characters in the forbidden range?" or something else entirely?

Comment: character "a" has hex code = "0061" , i want check  "0061"  not in range F900~FAFF(F900,F901,...,FAFF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, there is no need to convert so much between string, character, integer and string again... just get the integer value of each character and compare it to your range values. You can write integer constants in hex form with `&H` prefix.

```
Dim inTexts = "abc豈あああ"
For Each c As Char In inTexts
    Dim v = AscW(c)
    If v < &HF900 OrElse v > &HFAFF Then
        Console.Write("Character is out of range: ")
    Else
        Console.Write("Character is inside range: ")
    End If
    Console.WriteLine(c)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer:

```
Dim i As Integer  

Dim tmpChr As String
    toUniCodeHex = ""
    Dim iStart = Convert.ToInt32("F900", 16)
    Dim iEnd = Convert.ToInt32("FAFF", 16)
    For i = 0 To Len(inTexts) - 1
        'tmpChr = Convert.ToString(AscW(inTexts.Substring(i, 1)), 16)
        tmpChr = AscW(inTexts.Substring(i, 1)).ToString("x4")
        Dim v As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(tmpChr, 16)
        If v < iStart Or v > iEnd Then
           *'not bettween.*
        End If

    Next
```